# navigation-stack-actionlib

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every body

I am using actionlib to move the bsae of the robot to certain coordinates.

I give the coordinates as follows:

move_base_msgs::MoveBaseGoal goal;

goal.target_pose.pose.position.x = 2;

goal.target_pose.pose.position.y = 6;

double th=D2R*(atan2( msg.pose.pose.orientation.y, msg.pose.pose.orientation.y));

geometry_msgs::Quaternion gth = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

goal.target_pose.pose.orientation =gth;

Then the robot moves to the desired coordinates, however the robot has a  rotation behaviour when it reaches the goal.

How can avoid that rotation? I just want the robot to arrive to the desired position and stay there without any rotation.

In advance thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64662/navigation-stack-actionlib/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Increase the tolerance on the goal.  If it's too tight the robot will hunt as it gets close.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1